# Javascript Animation API : calling a function after each iteration

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm using Javascript [Element.animate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate)
 to create an infinite scroll animation.

here's a snippet of my code:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
var scroll = rows[i].animate([
  // keyframes
  { top: '-' + container.clientHeight + 'px' }, 
  { top: '600px' }
], { 
  // timing options
  duration: 10000,
  iterations: Infinity
});
}
```

my question is, can I call a function after each iteration ?

Comment: This might be a good candidate for CSS animation. But what you're looking for is `requestAnimationFrame` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: I think I can use CSS animation events such `animationiteration`, thanks!